# For each loop fails on else part

Tags: excel, vba

I would seek some help from you. I've been doing this plenty of times but this one time I can't bear with that.

I have got column of `ProductID` in two sheets and there is their description in one I want this description to be transferred to the other. If `ProdID` is not available then it has to say `Not available`. As a function

```
For Each product In Intersect(searcharea.Columns(1).Cells, searcharea.Parent.UsedRange)
    If product.Text = searchedvalue.Text Then
        description = Trim(product.Offset(0, 1).Text)
    Else description = "Not available"
    End If
Next product
productdescription = description
```

and I get all of the descriptions as not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I retry with similar function then may provide the same result than you expected, what I have found is that `Exit For` is very import in the looping, else it always return "Not found" in most case, hope it help you :)

```
Function test(lookR As Range, selectedRange As Range) As String

Dim lookValue As Range
Dim result As String

For Each lookValue In selectedRange.Cells
    If lookR.Value = lookValue.Value Then
        result = "ok"
        Exit For
    Else
        result = "Not found"
    End If
Next

test = result
End Function
```

Column B is where I enter my User Define Function
[image]

Comment: What you write would work but actually a line break instead of the `:` would be what I would expect here to look good (for better readability).

Comment: It does not works for me unfortunately. Productdescription itself is the name of the function, VBA does not let me. When I do productdescription = description it works only on the last entry

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Ya, the macro auto populate the : when i copy into my excel for testing, i think it is new update in excel 365, although I personal don't like it haha.

Comment: @lifeofthenoobie Maybe your problem was on the Productdescription function, it is hard to tell what is the actual issue?

Comment: Can't share the data as it is confidential unfortunately. What I want achieve is to let this function take offset (0,1) from 2nd sheet if gets ID from the first sheet column A (1) in the second sheet. If not available ID then it suppose to say "Not available". So the function would work similar to lookup but client needs it as separate function. for example productdescription=(A2,Sheet2!$A$1:$B$100) should give "Shovel" coz it has ID_01 in A2 sheet1, and ID_01 in second sheet has description of "Shovel". This function works fine but is lost at the part "Not available"

Comment: My problem is that it does all match only on last prod ID available from Sheet 2 while rest are "not available" even I can see them in both sheets

Comment: Check my edited answer, I think it is what you want??

Comment: Indeed. Thank you very much! You are great. Can the moderator delete other posts which contains a typo?

Answer (score 1):

A few questions arise:

- Why using a "function" when a "sub" fits better?
- Is "xCell" a typo?
- Where is "irow" declared / updated?

What I try to say with my sub vs. function:

```
For Each Product In Intersect(searcharea.Columns(1).Cells, searcharea.Parent.UsedRange)

    If Product.Text = searchedvalue.Text Then
        Description = Trim(xCell.Offset(0, 1).Text)
    Else
        Description = "Not available"
    End If

    cells(irow,2).value = Description
 
Next Product
```

Comment: Yes it is typo, had to change a little. Sorry. Irow is not my solution